# Dynamically applying missing alt to the image using jQuery showing error like "image must have an alt attribute" in w3c validation

Tags: jquery, html, w3c-validation

I get errors on w3c validation with the following code.

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://10.70.2.81/resource/images/Trustworthy-Guidance.png" >
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading text-align-left">Trustworthy Guidance</h4>
    <p class="text-align-left font-family-light">With up-to-date knowledge of various technology platforms and programming languages, we have the expertise to guide you to the right software solution for your business.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have added the following code for dynamically applying missing alt to the image using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var $img = $(this);
        var filename = $img.attr('src').replace(new RegExp("-", "g"), ' ');
        var filename1 = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1);    
        var attr = $(this).attr('alt');
        var title = $(this).attr('title');    

        if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false) {
            $img.attr('alt', filename1.substring(0, filename1.indexOf('.')));
        }
    });
});
```

Even I was getting same error like `image must have an alt attribute` in w3c validation. How to avoid that error using jQuery, otherwise i need to edit manually in all pages.

Comment: w3c validation don't execute js code. It just looks at the plain html response of your side. Crwalers and bots will even not execute js.

Comment: But i am applying alt tag from jquery on fly, but when i veiwing the source code alt is missing because dom is not able to read it on fly code

Comment: That is exactly like I told you. You can't use jQuery or other dynamic things, to make your code valid to w3c or bots. You have to response the correct html directly, or living with the invalid w3c checks. An missing `alt` attribute will not break your page. ;) But it is not good for SEO things too. Google will not see the attributes when you add them dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for info.i will change the html directly, because we need website with seo friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the images `alt` attribute (*neither anything else*) with JavaScript to your document, to become a valid HTML output!

Services like `w3c` validation, bots or crawlers will not execute JavaScript code. So on request of your page, your HTML is simply wrong and missing these information. Browsers may execute your JavaScript code and add the correct information to the DOM elements. For users with a common browser, everything seems to be fine, but for any automated system, it's not.

So it's in general a bad idea to do such things dynamically with JavaScript after the page load itself, because search engines can't collect the data correctly then. The images `alt` is an important attribute for search engines and they can't read this information in your example.

If you want to have a most SEO friendly page, you should really deliver the correct HTML on request, and not manipulate the content afterwards!